# Does anyone know what kind of surface is defined by $z=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2$?

Tags: surface-integrals

Does anyone know what kind of surface is defined by this equation?
$$z=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates.

Comment: It is a dumpling. To see this, convert to spherical coordinates

Comment: [WolframAlpha will plot it.](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3D%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E2) It's hard to tell from the static image, but the bottom is flattened (although not planar). @NinadMunshi's "dumpling" description seems appropriate. :)

Comment: I have tried spherical coordinates and got

$r =  \sqrt[3]{\cos \theta}$.

I wasn't sure if there was a specific name, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Anyway, "dumpling" is an excellent name. It is baptized. (;

Thank you all.

Comment: There is a nice 3D-plot in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803165/399263

Comment: Thanks, @zwim !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it has a name.

Given fixed $z,$ then:

$$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{z}-z^2$$ So you need $0\leq z\leq 1$ for  $x^2+y^2\geq 0.$ At $z=0$ and $z=1$ the set of solutions is the single point $(x,y)=(0,0).$ For any other $z$ in that range, the cross section curve is a circle.

Topologically, it is a sphere.

Its interior is convex. This is because the second derivative of $\sqrt z-z^2$ is negative.

For small $\epsilon>0$ the cross section at   $z=1-\epsilon$ has radius approximately $\sqrt{3\epsilon/2},$ and the cross section at $z=\epsilon$ is of radius $\approx \sqrt[4]{z},$ because when $z=\epsilon$, $\sqrt z-z^2\approx \sqrt z.$

This means that the surface is flat at both ends, like a sphere of radius $\frac{3}4$ and center $(0,0,1/4)$ near $z=1$ and an even flatter side near $z=0.$

When $z=1/2$ the radius of the circle cross-section  is at its largest, which is $\frac12\sqrt{2\sqrt 2-1}\approx 0.676.$

Comment: It seems that doesn't have a name, indeed. And I totally agree with your analysis, that $0\leq z \leq1$ limits the surface and the flatness regions. Thank you!!